# How can one boot from a WIN boot menue directly into a disk2vhd file (WIN 7)?

Tags: windows, boot

I created a .vhd file from my C: boot drive, using disk2vhd.
I did a copy of that file also. 
This copy has been tested for validity by VirtualBox - file is ok, works well.
I used copy, not to corrupt the other file with any VirtualBox impact.

The primary file I added to the WIN 7 boot menu using bcdedit.
It boots until a certain degree, than PC restarts on it’s own on BIOS level.

I mounted the .vhd file searching for any bootlog – none.
I noticed all examples I found booting from boot menu into a .vhd  are based on an installation into this .vhd. Non of the examples used a copy of an existing windows drive. However, in special this is very tempting to me.
I think I should add, 
the .vhd file is located at any disk, but not on the disk it was created from.

What is the process to make a disk2vhd created .vhd bootable for boot menu usage?

Thanks! - Tarik

Comment: Can you explain what commands you did with bcdedit or what your current boot configuration is showing? I thought VHD boot was only for Win7 Ultimate, but I could be wrong? Indeed their documentation (links below) points to installing a fresh Win7 for this so I can't help. Maybe your VHD isn't generalized, meaning its built for your specific HW, but the VHD boot needs generic HW (this has to do with the HAL).
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/knom/2009/04/07/windows-7-vhd-boot-setup-guideline
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/aviraj/2009/01/16/windows-7-boot-from-vhd-first-impression-part-1/

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/boot-to-vhd--native-boot--add-a-virtual-hard-disk-to-the-boot-menu
Here is a little google-fu to maybe find some more info:
`Windows 7 VHD Boot site:microsoft.com -social -answers`
`Native boot site:microsoft.com -social -answers`

Comment: You r right, I'm using WIN 7 Ultimate for this tests. 
bcdedit command are the documented ones, except the 
"bcdedit /set {newguid} detecthal on"
I'm share your opinion about generic hardware. At the moment I'm wondering if some "sysprep" runs will create this status.

Answer (score 1):

I think I issue is found.

The entries in bcdedit, althought OK at entry time, pointed somehow to wrong target in the VM VHD file. Reason was, there was a 2-partition boot solution. 
I completely removed all boot environment like "BOOT" directory, bootmgr, the good old ntldr, and so on.
Than I arranged a repair of boot environment by feeding vhd file into VirtualBox and apllying WIN7 Install CD boot repair options. Some manual work as well.
Issue solved. Now vhd file boots directly from bootmenue.
I was expecting the VM is notably faster and quicker, directly started  without VirtualBox-Overhead.

May be , it is here and there a bit faster, but not actually. From that point of view, using the VM in Virtual box makes more sence, given current use case.
However, if a VM is required but Virtual Box runs into issue because of drivers or USB problems, a direct boot can help.
Let us see, what WIN 10 can do in it's May edition :-)